# How can I invoke container managed security check from javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, jsf-2, security

I have a curious case that I dont know how to solve.

**Use Case:**
I have a legacy application built using plain old servlet and jsp and it needs to call another
application that is built using JSF 2.
JSF 2 is using container managed security using form based authentication.

In the legacy application, it has a page that lets user authenticate automatically into the JSF 2 application.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
       <script>
          function doLogin() {
             document.loginform.action="http://localhost:6060/MyApp/faces/j_security_check";
             document.loginform.submit();
          }
       </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
       <FORM id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST">
          <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username">
          <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password">
          <input type="button" onClick="doLogin()">
       </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

My problem is, how do I call the authentication mechanism programatically?
Both the legacy and the JSF 2 application has different authentication mechanism so I need to authenticate twice.

I tried with the code above and it works with a successful login.  But if the user logs an invalid user id and password, it resets back to the login page and not forwarded to the invalid user id/password page of jsf2 application.
Anybody has done this?

Comment: This JS code makes no sense. You can as good put that URL directly in `<form action>` attribute and replace the button by a `<input type="submit">` without onclick. As to the concrete problem, I do not fully understand it. Is the login page hosted on a different webapp than the webapp where you'd like to login? Do you have `<form-login-page>` and `<form-error-page>` configured on the webapp where you'd like to login?

Comment: Correct BalusC..it is a different web-app hosted in a different server.. It is just some sort of linking two web application with different server.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having an error page configured as below in your web.xml:

```
<form-error-page>/fail_login.html</form-error-page>
```

You can put a redirect in your `<form-error-page>` that will take you to appropriate web page.